# Flash SWF file opening on the top left of the screen and cannot be moved

Tags: flash, video-player

I've been designing a Flash animation for a client, and the animation looks perfect on my computer. However, its having problems on my client's computer though. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

She's using SWF & FLV Player and the flash animation just stuck on the top left corner, and it can't be dragged or moved.

What are the possible cause/solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what may cause the problem (never heard about "SWF & FLV Player" before) but one thing you could try is publishing the animation as a "Projector" (a stand-alone executable file) that your customer can run, instead of using her "SWF & FLV Player".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using windows--hopefully your client is too.

use the

**alt + space** Shortcut.  This will display the maximize/minimize optionsno matter where the window is.